# Magento - Show certain text for two payment methods in transactional email

Tags: email, if-statement, magento, transactional-email

so what I am trying to do is show certain text for two different payment methods in magento transactional emails. What I have written so far is:

```
{{if order.getPayment().getMethod()=='payone_advance_payment'}}
    This is A.
{{else}}
{{if1 order.getPayment().getMethod()=='SimpleAdminPayment5'}}
    This is B.
{{else1}}
    If it is neither A or B.
{{/if1}}
{{/if}}
```

What it does in the email is always show "This is A.". When I use

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethod()}}
```

It shows me the correct payment method I am using but it seems like as if he always thinks that the payment method I am using is `payone_advance_payment`.

So far I tried everything I know but nothing works. Do you have any idea?